How to change ref element when element isn't visible anymore?
In one of my components I've got a form that changes form depending on the value of a radio button.
My component looks like this:
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          class="radio"
          name="groupInput"
          type="radio"
          value="one"
          v-model="groupActive"
        />
        Group 1
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          class="radio"
          name="groupInput"
          type="radio"
          value="two"
          v-model="groupActive"
        />
        Group 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <input v-if="groupActive === 'one'" type="text" ref="defaultInput" />
    <select v-else ref="defaultInput">
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const groupActive = ref("one");
const defaultInput = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  defaultInput.value.focus();
});
</script>

Here's a working example.
When the component is mounted, defaultInput is focused. But when I change the value of the radio button, the <input> I was focusing on is no longer available and I'd like to focus on the new . How can I achieve this? Is it possible to update the ref value to the new <select> and then focus on it?

You can use onUpdated as well to handle reactive state changes after the initial mount.
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUpdated } from "vue";

const groupActive = ref("one");
const defaultInput = ref(null);

const focusInput = () => defaultInput.value.focus();
onMounted(focusInput);
onUpdated(focusInput);
</script>


Working Demo
